# Knockoutjs - I cannot manage to make fields to bind

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

---

Hello
I'm new to knockoutJs and it seems i'm doing it wrong somewhere.
here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/692/ .
I have correct values in ko object but they don't bind on my ui.
thx :)

Answer (score 1):

My bad. I used data-bind with ":" instead of "=". :)